# Type mismatch error when assigning a variable to an object of the same type

Tags: java, types, casting, mismatch

I'm working on an Iterator for a linked list class. I am assigning nodes to variables within an inner class and am getting a "Type mismatch" error. Relevant code is below.

```
public class RegLinkList<T> implements Iterable<T>{
    private Node<T> head;
public RegLinkList() {
        head = null;
    }   
 public class Node<T> {
   public Node<T> next = null;
   public T data = null;

   Node(T data){
        this.data = data;
    }
  }
    public class ListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>{
    Node<T> current = head;
    Node<T> previous = head;
```

I get this:

```
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from 
    RegLinkList<T>.Node<T> to RegLinkList<T>.Node<T>
```

Edit:
My current solution is an unchecked cast of

```
    public class ListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>{
    Node<T> current = (Node<T>) head;
    Node<T> previous = (Node<T>) head;
```

Comment: Your `Node` is introducing a second type named `T`. Remove the generic from `Node` (`RegLinkList` is already generic).

Comment: Alternatively (and better in my opinion) change the `Node` class to be static. --- And don't nest `ListIterator` inside `Node`.

Comment: I mis-typed regarding the nesting. As for static, I don't know if that will solve the problem. I found a fix but it has an unchecked cast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get this error is that the compiler does what you say and not what you mean. The `T` for `ListIterator` and the `T` of the `RegLinkList` are seen as two different types. It would become more clear if you used e.g. `U` instead of `T`.

A solution to your problem could be making the classes static and pass the `head` element to the constructor. That way you still declare different `T`s but because you pass the original element (and therefor "telling" the compiler that the one `T` is the same as the other), it will be happy. The following code is happily compiled (I added missing method implementations with no functionalities):

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class RegLinkList<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    private Node<T> head;

    public RegLinkList() {
        head = null;
    }

    public static class Node<T> {
        public Node<T> next = null;
        public T data = null;

        Node(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    public static class ListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
        Node<T> current;
        Node<T> previous;

        public ListIterator(Node<T> head) {
            current = head;
            previous = head;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public T next() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new ListIterator<T>(head);
    }
}
```